# WebFlux annotation Controller Mono empty unified response processing

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

When the Mono processing result is empty, SpringFlux add a unified response result.

```
@GetMapping
public Mono<Reaction<Object>> get() {
    return Mono.just(Reaction.fail())
            .filter(Reaction::isSuccessful);
}
```

A single Mono can use ****IfEmpty to implement this logic.

```
@GetMapping
public Mono<Reaction<Object>> get() {
    return Mono.just(Reaction.succeed(null))
            .filter(Reaction::isSuccessful)
            .defaultIfEmpty(Reaction.fail());
}
```

Api of function can use HandlerFilterFunction.

I now use annotation @RequestMapping, how should I implement it, and add a unified response result.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: `@GetMapping` == `@RequestMapping` so why should it be different?

Comment: @M.Deinum Deinum Code uses GetMapping or PostMapping. . . Specify the request method of the method, write RequestMapping in order to include more request methods, not limited to GetMapping

Comment: `@RequestMapping` matches all request types unless you limit it . However you have to really think if that is really what you want. A POST request is quite different from a GET request.

Comment: @M.Deinum Already deviated, Whether it is GetMapping, RequestMapping. . . They are all defining an entrance. Now if these entrances return Mono null, how can we capture him for unified processing

Comment: Your question, like your comments, is unclear. Your code uses `@GetMapping`, you state you are now using `@RequestMapping` you state with `@GetMapping` there is a unified response (and as `@GetMapping` is an `@RequestMapping` that should as well). So you r question is unclear or at least you are missing some understanding of the web related parts of Spring.

Comment: Sigh. I give up, Your problem description is unclear as are your comments which don't clarify your question. So unless you are going to clarify things in your question (or comments) this question won't receive an answer (because it cannot be answered due to being unclear).